# pytesseract: не верно распознается текст изображения

Tags: python, изображения, tesseract

Друзья, мне нужно распознать числа на изображении, но при помощи pytesseract.Image_to_string() не получается -  плохо считывает. Опытным путем, мне показалось, что проблема в фоне,но видимо не только. Менял фон, но изображение все равно плохо считывается. Прикладываю пример изображения.
Это полное изображение, я конечно обрезал, обесцвечивал. фото возможно  плохого качества, воспринимается не верно(третье фото результата)

[image: Изначальное изображение.]
[image: Результат обработки с фильтрами]

Добавляю код:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
img = Image.open('/home/zevs525/Рабочий стол/resA3.jpg')
r, g, b = img.split()
g.save('/home/zevs525/Рабочий стол/resB.jpg')
#r.show()
g.show()
#b.show()

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(g)

print(text)
```

Но проблема еще в чем: похожее фото воспринимается правильно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код ваш где? без кода никак.

Comment: Добавил код. спасибо

Comment: Не понимаю в чем проблема похожее фото pytesseract распознает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно делать предварительную обработку изображения. Изображение на сером фоне у вас и изображение с желтыми цифрами с точки зрения тессеракта совсем не похожи. Попробуйте сделать так:

Исходный файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter
import pytesseract


img = Image.open('tess_img.png')
# Увеличиваем контрастность:
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
img = enhancer.enhance(2)

# Преобразуем в черно-белый рисунок:
thresh = 200
fn = lambda x : 255 if x > thresh else 0
res = img.convert('L').point(fn, mode='1')

res.save("res.png") #сохранил предварительно обработанный файл для наглядности
```

Теперь картинка выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(res, lang="eng", config='--psm 6')
#обратите внимание на значение параметра pcm
print(text)
```

Результат:

> 342/436

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(res, lang="eng", config='--psm 13')
#играемся со значением параметра pcm
print(text)
```

> 342/430

Comment: спасибо за ответ,  сейчас попробую протестировать!

Comment: Всё, спасибо. Мне помогло, то что я изменил размер изображения(Методом отбора), Отобрал значение в config (В моем случае '--psm 6' при нужном размере изображения подходил всегда). И воспользовался советом выше, по обработке изображения!

Comment: Только еще вопрос. Как мне исправить то, что если цифры становятся красными они затираются фильтром?

Comment: Если цифры яркие, попробуйте вообще не использовать фильтры.

Comment: Да, это помогает